# Set Hudson build number from a script

Tags: hudson

Is there a way to set the next build number in Hudson from a script?

I have the nextBuildNumber plug-in installed, and attempted to use wget with --post-data, but that page appears to require login.

I have two steps of a chained build and I want to keep the build numbers in sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTTP authentication to log into your Hudson server with a user who has suitable privileges for scheduling a build.

The [authenticating scripted clients](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Authenticating+scripted+clients) page on the Hudson wiki describes this.

Comment: Hrm... I didn't specify it, but we're using Active Directory authentication, and as part of a large company, corporate IT hasn't been too keen to give us AD users for scripting purposes.  Not sure how I'll get around that limitation, but you've answered my original question.

Answer (score 1):

There's a file named `jobs/$JOBNAME/nextBuildNumber`. It contains the next build number to be used in plain text.